# Route to the wrong URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

I'm getting

> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"to_approve", :controller=>"microposts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
>
> No route matches {:action=>"to_approve", :controller=>"microposts",
>   :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

But it make no sense because I'm routing to different route

route.rb

```
  match '/microposts/:id/approve',  to: 'microposts#to_approve'  , via: [:get, :post], as: 'approve_micropost'
  match '/microposts/to_approve',  to: 'microposts#approve'  , via: :get
```

controller.rb

```
def show
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @microposts = @tag.microposts
end
```

show.html.rb

```
<%= render @microposts %>
```

_micropost.html.rb  - **Here is the line it shows the error on**

```
  <% if is_an_admin? %>
    <%= link_to "Approve", approve_micropost_path(micropost.id) %>
  <% end %>
```

micropost_controller.rb

```
  def approve
    @microposts = Micropost.unapproved
  end

  def to_approve
    micropost = Micropost.unapproved_by_id(params[:id])
    if micropost.update_attributes(approved: true)
      flash[:success] = "Approved!"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Not approved!"
    end

    redirect_back_or microposts_to_approve_path
  end
```

micropost.rb

```
  default_scope { where(approved: true).order('microposts.created_at DESC')}

  def self.unapproved
    self.unscoped.all.where(approved: false).order('microposts.created_at DESC')
  end

  def self.unapproved_by_id(id = nil)
    self.unscoped.all.where(id: id)
  end
```

You can see it tries to create `microposts_to_approve_path` with `:id` which obviously not exists, but I wrote `approve_micropost_path`.

What am I missing?

Plus, in route for `microposts_to_approve_path` I permitted `[:get, :post]` although I only want to allow access to to_approve method through `on_click` events (post?) and there is no view for it.. How should I rewrite this?

`rake routes`:

```
       microposts POST     /microposts(.:format)             microposts#create
        micropost DELETE   /microposts/:id(.:format)         microposts#destroy
approve_micropost GET|POST /microposts/:id/approve(.:format) microposts#to_approve
microposts_to_approve GET      /microposts/to_approve(.:format)  microposts#approve
```

On the error page, the parameters:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"4",
 "name"=>"tag name"}
```

***Solution***

The problem was because I use `default_scope` and than the object the I was working with wasn't OK.

Before fix

```
@microposts = @tag.microposts        #@microposts is CollectionProxy
```

After

```
@microposts = @tag.microposts.all    #@microposts is AssociationRelation
```

Once I've change to `.all` the problem was solved.

BTW, is it a bug? In my prespective `default_scope` shouldn't change the default behavior..

Comment: Show your `rake routes` result

Comment: Please show your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to only respond to a post, then try changing your link to use the method 'post'.

```
<% if is_an_admin? %>
  <%= link_to "Approve", approve_micropost_path(micropost.id), method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

Conversely, if you want it to route to microposts#to_approve on a get, then make your link explicitly call get.

```
<% if is_an_admin? %>
  <%= link_to "Approve", approve_micropost_path(micropost.id), method: :get %>
<% end %>
```

Then you should be routed to microposts#to_approve using POST.  However, since you re allowing either action to take place, make sure in your `to_approve` action, you'll have to check for request type.  Such as:

```
#microposts controller

def to_approve
  if request.post?
    # Do post related things
  else
    # Do get related things
  end
end
```

Sidenote *** using the `to_approve` action on the `approve` url, and using the `approve` action on the `to_approve` url is confusing, things you might forget why-you-did-what-you-did when you look at the code 6 months from now.

*Edit*

An alternative might be to break apart the routes so you aren't calling an `if` statement in your controller.

*route.rb*

```
post '/microposts/:id/approve',  to: 'microposts#approve', as: 'approve_micropost'
get '/microposts/:id/to_approval', to: 'microposts#to_approve', as: 'micropost_approvals'
resources :microposts
```

Comment: That what made me thinking if I need to refactor here to something else. But this is the way I though about, if you have a suggestion you are welcome to write it ;) Plus note here that you only refereed to the second issue and not the first one (the error)

Comment: Aah, I tested your code and for me it depended on the position of your routes in the route.rb.  Routes are processed top-down so you'll want to make sure that your match lines are above your resources :microposts line.  Additionally, adding the `method` in the link itself forced it to behave correctly and not error.

Comment: I've put the match before the resources, and I've put `method: :post` to the `link_to` but still same error. Can you also clear what you wrote in the edit, I did not follow, there is no if in my controller.

Comment: What version of ruby and what version of rails? maybe there's something I'm missing.  Can you post your code (github, bitbuckets, etc) ?

Comment: Without looking at your code, or testing it, it's tough for me to say - I've created this code example for you of what works, feel free to let me know why that isn't what you need and I can be more helpful. ::: https://github.com/trh/microposts_test_app

Comment: See my edit, fix the problem. I'll still be happy if you explain your edit for my refactor.